# When I tried to call a class in Java, an error occured

Tags: java

When I tried to call a class called "ShowHistory" in Java, an error shows: "The type ShowHistory must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)"

Here is my code:

```
    public class ShowHistory extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   ...
    }
```

The IDE recommended me to make this class to be an abstract class, but when I convert it to be abstract, another piece of code goes wrong:

```
            ShowHistory frame = new ShowHistory();
```

It shows: "Cannot instantiate the type ShowHistory".

Is there any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: did you implement all the methods from ActionListener ?

Comment: Error messages are pretty helpful.

Comment: Yes. Is there any problem of using ActionListener?

Comment: Sorry I am not a native English speaker and I think I am new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The type ShowHistory must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

What this means is that for your class `ShowHistory` to implement `ActionListener`, it must implement all of the methods defined by the interface. In this case, that is the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ... }
```

When you changed `ShowHistory` to `abstract`, you made it so that ShowHistory can't be instantiated, and it's child classes (who may be instantiated, if not abstract) will be responsible for defining the methods in `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 1):

When a class `implements` an interface, it needs to provide an implementation for each of the interface's methods.

Here, the interface in question is [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). It contains a single method, [`actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29).

Your class, `ShowHistory`, needs to provide an implementation for this method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ... }
```

The error message is telling you that currently the class doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Then for the first error message you just need to implement a method `actionPerformed` in your class so it overrides the one from the interface ActionListener. When a class implements an interface, it has to implement every methods that the interface contains.

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), `ActionListener` only have one method, `actionPerformed`, that you need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an abstract class: That's the definition of `abstract`!

You can however instantiate a *subclass*, possibly as an anonymous class,. For example:

```
ShowHistory frame = new ShowHistory() {
    // Add methods you might need to implement here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

when you implement any Interface or extends any class you have to implement all the methods defined in interface or abstract class extended.

if you want the specialized class (Lower in same hierarchy) to provide the implementation you can make your class abstract (as suggested by ide to you),but in that case you won't be able to create the object of this class, and you will be required to create objects of the new class which provides the implementation